# How to return something from a Concern and update a record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport-concern

I want to move some class methods for some of my models that are the same to a concern.
One method takes an input and returns something which then should be used to update a record like this:

```
def create_sort_title
    self.sort_title = self.title.gsub(/^the |^a |^an /i, '').gsub(/'|"|!|\?|-/, '').gsub(/(?<!\w) /,'')
end
```

While it's clear that I need to refactor it to take an input:

```
def create_sort_title(title)
    self.sort_title = title.gsub...
...
```

I don't understand how I can RETURN a value to update a record - i. e. how to replace the self.sort_title above with something that then is used to update the sort_title of the corresponding record?

The method is called by a before_safe hook:

```
before_save :create_sort_title
```

(and I understand once I take an argument, I need to use a lambda like this:

```
before_save -> { create_sort_title(title) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to pass any arguments if you're using a concern that is included on the model. When you do `include ConcernName` you're adding class and/or instance methods on the model class/instance itself. So your `create_sort_title` method that is called from `before_save` callback will have access to all instance methods, including `title` and will work as-is just fine